# markdown preview / final result, issue with quoted "*"

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, markdown-preview

in this answer by Olivier Dulac: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16989110/592540 there appears to be a difference between the preview of the answer when editing and when the final result is published.

In this first screenshot you can see the published answer. In the marked area it should say `or "$*", or $*)`, but it interpreted the asterisks as an emphasis zone.

[image: The final result]

So I went to edit the question, but then in the preview the result was ok::

[image: When going to edit the question, preview is OK]

I really don't know if the proper markdown should escape the asterisks or not so they display correctly instead of being interpreted, but the bug is that the preview and the final result is different.

I tried making a minor edit so the markdown was reparsed and the html regenerated, because I saw on another bug report that the html is regenerated only on edits and that maybe the bug was solved in the meantime (previous edit was from 2013), but the bug is still there.

Comment: A little tip regarding the last paragraph: On the revisions page (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16989110/revisions in this case), the Markdown is rendered on-demand. So to test if this has been fixed in the meantime (an absolutely valid idea), you can check the current server-side rendering behavior by clicking the "edited" link.